# Random Record without Duplicates

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am allowing users to find a random record from a list of posts. I define the random function in my model like so:

```
def self.random
   if (c = count) != 0
 find(:first, :offset => rand(c))
   end
end
```

I would really like to limit the possibility of duplicates. There are not a large number of posts so I am not worried about performance. Is there a simple way to ensure that all posts are displayed in a random order before cycling through the same posts again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what SQL storage engine you're using, many implement a RAND() function, so you could do something like this:

```
MyModel.order('RAND()').all
```

To return all posts in a random order.

Comment: This will be quite slow for bigger tables. http://www.electrictoolbox.com/msyql-alternative-order-by-rand/

Comment: Definitely... but he said there are not a large number of posts, so I'm not sure a bigger function is really necessary.

Comment: Please note that if you use SQLite as your database engine you will need to use "MyModel.order('RANDOM()').all" instead of "MyModel.order('RAND()').all"